# A region of my ROC curve is below the random line

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection, roc

I have some targets in an hyperspectral image and I want to detect them. I proposed a detector and then I analysed its performance via the Receiver Operating Characteristics (ROC) curves.

When the targets to detect have a very low signal to noise ratio (that is, the targets are very weak in the image and so their detection is very challenging especially for very small probability of false alarms Pfa values), I am always obtaining like the following ROC curve.

[image]

This is not my figure, but I am obtaining similar to this ROC curve. So my curve is below the random line for `Pfa<=0.1`. 
I am wondering if it is normal? is it acceptable to have a region of the ROC curve below the random line? and if yes, so how this can be justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ROC shows true and false positive ratios for increasing threshold. With the threshold at one extreme, everything is classified negative, and so you have 0% true positives and 0% false positives. With the threshold at the other extreme you have 100% true positives and 100% false positives. In between the two extremes, anything can happen. In this particular case, as you increase the threshold from the first extreme, you start classifying negative samples as positive, and so you increase the false positive rate without increasing the true positive rate.

In principle there's nothing wrong with this. What matters is that you can find a point (a threshold) where the compromise between true and false positive ratios are satisfactory. That is the point at which you'll operate your system. And because you want the choice of threshold to be robust, you want that the ROC changes slowly around that point. But what it does far away from your operating point doesn't influence your system. (This is why I think that the "Area under the Curve" measure for performance is not useful.)

However, what your ROC does show you is that the samples that your system thinks are most obviously positive are actually negative. Maybe you didn't model your samples properly?

Comment: Thank you Cris for your answer. In fact, I revised model a lot and there are no problems with my samples. I think this is because my target has a very low signal to noise ratio and so its detection is very challenging. So obviously, the detection might be very poor (=0) for small probablity of false alarms. Do you think I am correct?

Comment: But for very small chance of false alarms (low false positive ratio) your detector should be picking out only the most obvious targets. Instead, it picks only some non-targets. Then you increase the threshold (sensitivity), and it starts picking up mostly real targets, with very few false positives. That is strange. Possible, but strange. Unless your test images have a few non-targets that look a lot like targets.

Comment: The other option is that you're computing the ROC wrong?

Comment: I don't think because I revised a lot my computing for the ROC. I think this is normal because the target has a very low fill fraction and so its detection ar very small probablity of false alarm is very challenging.